# Lost in pagination system

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to implement a simple pagination system in my album script. And i've tried several things, and read some tutorials on the internet but none of them suits me? Probebly because i'm using PDO, and all tutorials are in mysql.

Can anyone help me a bit?

```
<?php

$result = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM album WHERE bla = :bla');

$result->execute(array(':bla'=> $bla));

$numrows = $result->rowCount();

if($numrows != 0){
    foreach ($result as $row) {

         echo '
                <div class="imgwrap">
                    <a href="show.php?photo='.$row['id'].'" title="'.$row['caption'].'"><img src="'.$row['location'].'" alt="'.$row['beschrijving'].'" /></a>
                </div>
            ';
    }   
}else{
    echo 'There are no images!';
}


?>

</div>
```

Comment: What specifically is your problem?

Comment: this is not how pagination works. You are currently returning all the data. [Here is a very good library](http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/29.html) that i always use.

Comment: For pagination your query always needs a LIMIT. For example `LIMIT 0, 10`

Comment: Pagination without `LIMIT` ?

Comment: Just letting you know, naming the problem is important.

Comment: Actually, you are just doing a basic listing of your data. What have you tried to make something that could look like "pagination" ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the `WHERE bla = :bla` part of his query represents the pagination, but didn't add it because it's not the part that's broken here. However, you should be sure to include your code as-is Kets\; I've tried posting partial code here and it normally just causes confusion.

Comment: @Mister If `:bla` contains the limit clause, that *is* what is broken.

Comment: I thought I knew, but I apparently did not. That is likely the part that's broken. @deceze

Comment: That's the basic code for getting al my pictures from my album. I've removed tries from my previous code. This is clean, so you guys can see and help me the best way for including a pagination system here.

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't here to write code for you. Stackoverflow is there to correct mistakes in not working code. Your code is working... You simply didn't even try pagination. Like everyone told you. You need a 'LIMIT' in your query. And stick to PDO, mysqli_* is crap

Comment: What have you tried if you’ve tried “several things”, and what is the problem you’re facing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a matter of fact, databases do not have much to do with the pagination *algorithm*. Which is going to be the same, no matter which database or database driver is used, or if even no database involved at all.

If you understand the *idea*, particular driver will be of no matter. Strictly speaking,  database operations will take only 2 calls, which can be implemented easily with any driver.

From database we will need the data itself and total number of records.

In order to obtain these, we will use two MySQL features:

- `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` / `FOUND_ROWS()` to get total number of rows
- `LIMIT` clause to limit the amount of selected data,

To display links to pages you will need to know the current page and the total number of pages.

```
<?php
$per_page = 10;

//let's get the page number
$cur_page = 1;
if (isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] > 0) 
{
    $cur_page = $_GET['page'];
}

// then define starting record
$start = ($cur_page - 1) * $per_page;

//now let's get the data
$sql  = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM Board LIMIT ?, ?";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(1, $start,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $per_page,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
$data = $stmt->fetchAll();

//  and total number of rows
$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT FOUND_ROWS()");
$rows = $stmt->fetchColumn();

// here we calculate number of pages.
$num_pages = ceil($rows / $per_page);

//we have to define this variable to display list of pages
$page = 0;
include 'template.tpl.php';
```

Now, as soon as we have all our data ready, we may let it out, using native PHP as a *template*:

```
Records found: <b><?=$rows?></b><br><br>
<? foreach ($data as $row): ?>
    <?=++$start?>. 
    <a href="?id=<?=$row['id']?>">
         <?=$row['title']?>
    </a>
    <br>
<? endforeach ?> 

<br>
Pages: 
<? while ($page++ < $num_pages): ?>
    <? if ($page == $cur_page): ?>
         <b><?=$page?></b>
    <? else: ?> 
        <a href="?page=<?=$page?>"><?=$page?></a>
    <? endif ?> 
<? endwhile ?>
```

However, this is bare minimum, including no such essential parts like cutting down number of pages displayed and support for additional WHERE parameters.

PDO makes it a little verbose - so, it's better to get yourself some more sophisticated driver.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a reasonable tutorial on the key ideas behind a pagination system.

The basic concepts are irrelevant to the php/mysql module you are using to get to your database.

The basic idea is to :-

1. Find out how many rows in your table(s) you have to show.
2. Decide how many lines to show on a page.
3. Keep track of what page you are on.
4. Understand the `LIMIT` syntax of mysql, so that you can get only the relevant rows from the database on each new page request.

[Pagination tutorial](http://www.phpfreaks.com/tutorial/basic-pagination) this should help.